# cat blocking when called via subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, shell

Im having a unexpected behaviour of the linux cat when its called via subprocess.Popen().

The Python script is structured like such:

```
import os, subprocess

def _degrade_child_rights(user_uid, user_gid):
    def result():
        os.setgid(user_gid)
        os.setegid(user_gid)
        os.setuid(user_uid)
        os.seteuid(user_uid)
    return result

child = subprocess.Popen("cat /home/myuser/myfolder/screenlog.0", 
preexec_fn=_degrade_child_rights(0, 0), shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

When i check the executed shell-command with ps aux | grep cat it shows me that python successfully run the shell-command.

```
> ps aux | grep cat
root     21236  0.0  0.0   6564   780 pts/1    S    20:49   0:00 /bin/sh -c cat /home/myuser/myfolder/screenlog.0
root     21237  0.0  0.0  11056   732 pts/1    S    20:49   0:00 cat /home/myuser/myfolder/screenlog.0
root     21476  0.0  0.0  15800   936 pts/1    S+   20:52   0:00 grep --color=auto cat
```

However, the cat command never finishes.

I also outsourced the cat $file command to a bash-script. Then bash executes my cat-call, but also blocks.

When i manually execute cat $file it runs like expected, so a not existing EOF at the end of the file is also impossible.

I think, the '/bin/sh -c' added by Popen messes somehow with the correct execution of cat $file.

Can i somehow prevent this?

Comment: It seems your not reading form the subprocess pipe that cats stdout is connected to. That means it will block once the buffer of the pipe gets full. You need to read data from the pipe, or to connect stdout of the subprocess to stdout of the Python process.

Comment: No, the `sh -c` has nothing to do with the problem. Passing `shell=True` tells Python you want to actually run `sh -c "cat /home/myuser/myfolder/screenlog.0"` -- if you *didn't* want that, you'd want to leave the `shell=True` argument off, and reform the rest of the command to represent a valid argv list. The quotes aren't visible in `ps`'s output because `ps` isn't specified in such a way as to ensure that its output is reusable as command input; it doesn't visually distinguish between syntactic and literal spaces.

Comment: (so, you can't in `ps` output tell the difference between `./myprog "hello world"` and `./myprog hello world`; if you want the *actual* argv, the best practice is to pull it out of procfs, where it's available in NUL-delimited form).

Comment: @Magnus Reftel you are right, that was the problem. 
Austin Yates your answer is correct, but did not fit for my needs. 

My way to go was reading from the pipe via readline() in a thread that started right after the Popen() call.
The started thread then put the output of the readline to a queue, which has a timeout support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the communicate method for the Popen object:

> `Popen.communicate(input=None)` 
>   Interact with process: Send data to
>   stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
>   Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a
>   string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be
>   sent to the child.
>
> `communicate()` returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.
>
> Note The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if
>   the data size is large or unlimited.

There is more info in the [`subprocess` python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)